# branching process distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Source: Probability with Martingale by Williams Page 11. Target: self study.

We are looking at the branching process with typical number of children of $X$ to have a geometric distribution $P(X=x)=pq^k$, $k\in \textbf Z^+$ where $0<p<1$ and $q+p=1$. We define the generating function $f$ of $X$ as the map $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$, where $f(\theta):=\textbf E(\theta^X)=\sum_{x\in \textbf Z^+}\theta^k\textbf P(X=k)$. For the variable $X_f^{(n+1)}$ representing the number of children of the $r$th animal in the $n$th generation. Then $Z_m$ signifies the size of the $m$th generation and $Z_{n+1}=X_1^{(n+1)}+\ldots+X_{Z_n}^{(n+1)}$. We assume $Z_0=1$. I was able to prove the result $f_{n+1}(\theta)=f_n(f(\theta))$. The eventual extinction probability is defined as $\pi$, with $\pi=f(\pi)$. We also have $\mu = \textbf E(X)$.

The author writes:
Suppose that $\mu<1$. In this case, it is interesting to ask: what is the distribution of $Z_n$ conditioned by $Z_n\neq 0$? We find that $E(\theta^{Z_n}|Z_n\neq 0)=\frac{f_n(\theta)-f_n(0)}{1-f_n(0)}$.

Q) Why is this expression true? I see that $E(\theta^{Z_n})=f_n(\theta)$ and then I expect the use of Bayes' theorem here to take care of the conditioning $Z_n\neq 0$, but I don't see how to get the expression on the right.

Edit: I was able to prove this using law of total expectations. I showed that $\textbf E(\theta^{Z_n}|Z_n\neq 0)=\frac{\theta(\mu-1)}{\mu^{n+1}(1-\theta)+\mu\theta-1}$.

There after the author also claims: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(Z_n=k|Z_n\neq 0)=(1-\mu)\mu^{k-1}$.

$\textbf{I don't understand where this came from}. $

I can see that $\textbf E(\theta^{Z_n}|Z_n\neq 0)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\theta^k \textbf P(Z_n=k|Z_n\neq 0)$.